# Include external DLL within the project's build in VS 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, build

I have 2 solutions in VS 2013(c#), SolutionA contains the website etc, SolutionB contains common logic like password generators etc (that I also use for other solutions).

SolutionB uses an external Bcrypt dll (among others). However, when I include a reference to the projects/dll's from SolutionB in my SolutionA, I'm required to manually reference the dll's used in SolutionB. So my SolutionA still needs a reference to the Bcrypt DLL...even though this is only used in the SolutionB code.

How can I include this external Bcrypt dll into the dll's that are built from SolutionB, so I dont need to reference anything else in SolutionA but my own SolutionB dll's?

Thanks, hope it's not too confusing :)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2009/04/08/unable-to-load-dll-bcrypt-dll-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-exception-from-hresult-0x8007007e.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there are various options like **ILMerge**/custom tools etc. to embed one DLL into another. here is a CODE way of doing it:

1. In Solution B, go to BCrypt.dll and do `'copy local' = false` in the properties.
2. Add the DLL as a part of the solution. (if not already)
3. Set the build action of BCrypt.dll to `Embedded Resource`.
4. Now in the entry point/start up code of the Solution B DLL, subscribe to the `AssemblyResolve` event as follows:

5.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
{
 string dllName = args.Name + ".dll";    

 using (var stream= Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(dllName))
 {
  byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
  stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, stream.Length);

  return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
 }
};
```

1. Basically what we have done is embedded Bcrypt.dll into Solution B's DLL, so that when Solution B's dll is referenced, we also have BCrypt.dll available.
2. And when .NET assembly-resolution fails, the above event is raised for any custom assembly loading and we provide our BCrypt's address to the flow.

and if `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` doesn't work above, it might be trying to search of BCrypt in Solution A's resource stream.

Try

```
Assembly.Load("SolutionBDLL")
```

Comment: thx, used ILmerge and tried to create a postbuild script which eventually worked.